# html and java script for bar chart with data from data base

Tags: javascript, html, mysql

I'd like to get my current table presentation of data called from MySQL data base tables, to look better, as a bar chart or pie chart. I'm on Dreamweaver CS5.5 and don't have CF. I'd prefer to write it into the current page (shown below) in HTML and JavaScript. Does anyone have any ideas please? My current page is attached. Thanks, Rose

```
<title>Results4</title>

</head>
<body>

<form action="resultsparta4.php" method="post">
<script>
function myFunction()
{
window.print();
 }
</script>
<?
$client_id =$_POST['clientid'];

print "<table border=5 align= \"center\" width=\"75%\"  >";
print "<tr><td><h2>Results page 4: Your results are ranked below </h2></b></p> </td></tr>";

// access the apache web server

 $host = "localhost";
 $user = "root";
 $pwd = "";

 $connect = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pwd);

 // set up the database variable

 $db = "clients";

 //set up the select query

 $query = "SELECT a.client_id, a.percent, b.percent, c.percent, d.percent
 FROM apples a, oranges b, pears c,
grapefruit d
WHERE a.client_id = b.client_id 
AND b.client_id = c.client_id 
AND c.client_id = d.client_id
ORDER BY client_id DESC";

// connect to a database and create a query

$result = mysql_db_query($db,$query);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$list=array();

$a = $row[1]; 
$b = $row[2];
$c = $row[3];
$d = $row[4];

$list = array('apples %'=>$a,
'oranges %'=>$b,'pears %'=>$c,'grapefruit %'=>$d);
print "<table border=5 align= \"center\" width=\"75%\"  bgcolor=\"BD9DFF\">";
print "<tr><td><h2>Section </h2></td><td><h2>Percent 
</h2></td></tr>";
arsort($list);
foreach ($list as $key => $val)

{ 
//set up the table and headings
print "<tr><td><h2>$key</h2></td><td><h2>$val</h2></td></tr>";
} 

//close the table
print "</table>";

?>
<?
$client_id =$_POST['clientid'];

print "<table border=5 align= \"center\" width=\"75%\"  >";
?>
print "<table border=5 align= \"center\" width=\"75%\"  bgcolor=\"BD9DFF\">";
print "<tr><td><h2>Section </h2></td><td><h2>Percent</h2></td></tr>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you looked at any javascript libraries for creating charts and the like: http://www.chartjs.org/

Comment: Try http://www.highcharts.com/

Comment: Thank you to haakym and Paul and I will follow up on those links. I'm trying to avoid downloading a free chart that delivers my data back to a third party for example google or who ever, which is why I want to write it for myself. I'll look anyway, cheers, Rosie